# Groupid is duplicate of parent groupid in warning in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, warnings, pom.xml

I have a 4 pom.xmls in which it has parent tag which has group in it eclipse gives warning stating that duplicate group id. I have removed it but worrying will there be any effect in higher environments.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>acf.oyyyldc.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>olyyydc.common</artifactId>
        <version>6.15.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
<groupId>acf.oyyyldc.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>oyyyldc.w</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, I suppose, but here goes... Health warning: I am new to using multi-Maven projects. I found this reply, which said to change the Eclipse preferences from 'warning' to 'ignore'.
[version is duplicate of parent version #1334](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/1334)

I don't understand why this is a warning, since most of the examples I have found, use the same GroupId for parent and modules. The 'same version' warning does make some sense as I would expect these to diverge, even if the same at the start.